# Graphhopper Map-Matching looses time attribute

Tags: time, gpx, map-matching, graphhopper

I try to use the [Graphhopper Map-Matching](https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching). My GPX source file looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx version="1.0" creator="GPSBabel - http://www.gpsbabel.org" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0">
  <time>2015-10-14T05:42:02.857Z</time>
  <bounds minlat="49.021236667" minlon="8.430790000" maxlat="49.023695000" maxlon="8.433425000"/>
  <trk>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="49.021240000" lon="8.431605000">
        <time>2015-08-24T05:48:08.916Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="49.021240000" lon="8.431605000">
        <time>2015-08-24T05:48:08.927Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="49.021240000" lon="8.431605000">
        <time>2015-08-24T05:48:08.938Z</time>
      </trkpt>

      <!-- much much more points -->

      <trkpt lat="49.021415000" lon="8.431866667">
        <time>2015-08-24T05:50:29.128Z</time>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

Then I run:

```
./map-matching.sh action=import datasource=mypath/karlsruhe.osm.pbf       vehicle=car

./map-matching.sh action=match gpx=mypath/myfile.gpx
```

But the resulting gpx file lost all it's times.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creator="Graphhopper" version="1.1" xmlns:gh="https://graphhopper.com/public/schema/gpx/1.1">
<metadata><copyright author="OpenStreetMap contributors"/><link href="http://graphhopper.com"><text>GraphHopper GPX</text></link><time>1970-01-01T01:00:00+01:00</time></metadata>
<trk><name>GraphHopper MapMatching</name><trkseg>
<trkpt lat="49.020944" lon="8.430902"><time>1970-01-01T01:00:00+01:00</time></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="49.021033" lon="8.431043"><time>1970-01-01T01:00:00+01:00</time></trkpt>

<!-- some more points -->

<trkpt lat="49.020944" lon="8.430902"><time>1970-01-01T01:00:00+01:00</time></trkpt></trkseg></trk></gpx>
```

I tried some different time formats but nothing worked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp has to be calculated to be included for the new snapped path. This is a feature not yet done. See [this discussion](https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/time-stamps-in-match-result-what-is-the-proposed-way-for-implementation/199) for more information.

Comment: Okay, maybe a small note in the Readme.md might be helpfull that this feature is not yet ready.

Comment: Feel free to open a PR or issue